# Is it a bad idea to use the invocation list of an inherited event?

Tags: c#, events, observablecollection

I have a class that inherits from `ObservableCollection<T>`.  In that class I have a method that changes the collection internally and for which I'd like to suppress `CollectionChanged` events.

```
public class ContentBlockList : ObservableCollection<int> {
    public void SomeMethod() {
        var handlers = CollectionChanged.GetInvocationList();

        foreach (NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler handler in handlers) {
            CollectionChanged -= handler;
        }

        // do stuff here

        foreach (NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler handler in handlers) {
            CollectionChanged += handler;
        }
    }
}
```

Intuitively it seems like this should work since I'm accessing the event from within its containing object.  Unfortunately, the compiler says

> The event 'ObservableCollection.CollectionChanged' can only
>   appear on the left hand side of += or -=

I can get the code to work if I override both `CollectionChanged` and `OnCollectionChanged()`, essentially replacing the .NET versions with copies of my own.  However, having to do something like that makes me suspicious that I'm ignoring some reason why doing this is a bad idea in the first place.  Thanks for any thoughts on this.

Comment: Since unsubscribing and then subscribing to the event will be a relatively slow process, wouldn't it be easier to simply override both the `CollectionChanged` and `OnCollectionChanged` methods and call their respective `base` method. Have a flag that shows you are updating internally allowing you control over the event's being raised within your overridden methods, only after you are finished you could explicitly raise the `CollectionChanged` with the `Reset` action.

Comment: That's a great idea, and more indicative of the behavior I'm looking for.  I'll be glad to accept that as the answer if you post it.  Thanks.

Comment: Raising `Reset` is important, make sure you don't forget, or else things binding to your list may get out of sync.

Comment: `do stuff here` is actually reloading the list from a database.  I'm thinking that the better action in that case is `Replace` and not `Reset`.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As unsubscribing and re-subscribing to an event is a relatively (not really painful but I don't know how many subscribers there is likely to be) slow process I would recommend that you look into overriding both the the `OnCollectionChanged` and `OnPropertyChanged` methods for the base `ObservableCollection`.

So have something that resembles:

```
public class ContentBlockList : ObservableCollection<int>
{
    private bool internallyUpdating;

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        this.internallyUpdating = true;

        // Do Stuff (Add to base collection)

        this.internallyUpdating = false;
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(@"Count");
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(@"Item[]");
        this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }

    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(this.internallyUpdating)
        {
            return;
        }

        base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(this.internallyUpdating)
        {
            return;
        } 

        base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
    }
}
```

What this allows for is the ability to suppress the events being raised while you update internally but doing this in a way that means you do not have to unsubscribe and resubscribe to events.

When adding to this collection normally (i.e. with `contentBlockList.Add(1)`) you'll fall straight through to calling the base event. But when you are trying to update internally you'll suppress these events until you have finished.
I'd say this is both more efficient in terms of performance but also much neater code than what you were looking at.

On a last note I'd also say that the `NotifyCollectionChangedEventAction` that you provide is `Reset`. You've probably done quite a big change to the collection and to handle it you'll want any subscriber to have to refresh their look on the collection, be it a control in a WPF view or even another class that uses the collection.

Answer (score 0):

better use this :

```
public class ContentBlockList : ObservableCollection<int>
    {
        ContentBlockList()
        {
            this.CollectionChanged += ContentBlockList_CollectionChanged;
        }

        void ContentBlockList_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

if you maintain your code try this

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ContentBlockList pp = new ContentBlockList();
        pp.CollectionChanged += pp_CollectionChanged;
        pp.CollectionChanged += pp_CollectionChanged1; 
        pp.Add(11112);

        pp.SomeMethod();
    }

    void pp_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    void pp_CollectionChanged1(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }


}

public class ContentBlockList : ObservableCollection<int>
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        var handlers = CollectionChanged.GetInvocationList();

        foreach (NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler handler in handlers)
        {
            CollectionChanged -= handler;
        }

        // do stuff here

        foreach (NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler handler in handlers)
        {
            CollectionChanged += handler;
        }
    }

    public override event System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
}
```

Comment: Events don't fire unless I also override `OnCollectionChanged()`.  Regardless, the question isn't whether I can get this to work--I can--it's whether there's a reason I shouldn't.  Thanks.

Comment: it is a good idea to inherit  ObservableCollection<T> if you have a specific logic.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you need to interrupt firing of `CollectionChanged` to do some work silently. So you can create boolean field like `__FireCollectionChanged` and then override `OnCollectionChanged()` to do:

```
protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (__FireCollectionChanged)
        base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
}
```

Then you can control whether event is fired by that boolean field.

And answering the actual question: you can't use the invocation list directly, because the event is not the delegate type field. It's basically just two methods `add` and `remove` for subscribe/unsubscribe behavior. Underlying delegate field is created behind the scenes and you typically don't want to use it.